# Condition not satisfied when comparing empty Strings in Spock

Tags: groovy, spock

I'm trying to check that 2 strings are equal but I'm hitting. Both Strings are empty:

```
Condition not satisfied:

versionTagPrefix == ""
|                |
""               false
                 2 differences (0% similarity)
                 ("")
                 (--)
```

I've also tried equals:

```
Condition not satisfied:

"".equals(versionTagPrefix)
   |      |
   false  ""
```

Versions:

```
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.0.1'
testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0"
```

Comment: Are you sure both strings are empty? What's the output of `versionTagPrefix.bytes`? Is the `versionTagPrefix` a string for sure?

Comment: Is versionTagPrefix an instance of java.lang.String?

Comment: If spock You can just use `!versionTagPrefix`. There no need for comparison here.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know, groovy has many implementations of Strings.
When you see messages in output/error stream you are probably looking at value of `toString()` instead of actual content of object.

To go in deep and debug, use `.properties` attribute on objects.

### For example :

#### 1 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl

```
groovy:000> i=10; s1="$i"; "type=${s1.class}\n
                            content=${s1.properties}\n
                            out=${s1.toString()}"
===> type=class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
     content=[values:[10],
              class:class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl,
              bytes:[49, 48], strings:[, ], valueCount:1]
     out=10
```

#### 2. java.lang.String

```
groovy:000>s2="10"; "type=${s2.class}\n
                        contents=${s2.properties}\n
                        out=${s2.toString()}"
===> type=class java.lang.String
     contents=[class:class java.lang.String, bytes:[49, 48], empty:false]
     out=10
```

#### And can be many implementations....

---

Though in this case `s1 == s2`, you might have a situation where `s1 != s2` but `s1.toString() == s2.toString()`

```
assert versionTagPrefix?.toString() == ""
```